# Radio Button windows form not working

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have implemented c# code with 3 radio buttons, but it's not working correctly:

[image]

It only shows the first one and second one, but doesn't shown the last. I tried with using sender object but it didn't work.

the code:

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
    {
        double Weight2 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
        double LowW = Weight2 * 24 * 1.2;
        String s = Convert.ToString(LowW);
        richTextBox1.Text = "The calories per day for low actaivity is : " + s;
    }
    else if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
    {
        double Weight2 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
        double LowW = Weight2 * 24 * 1.3;
        String s = Convert.ToString(LowW);
        richTextBox1.Text = "The calories per day for low actaivity is : " + s;
    }
        else if (radioButton3.Checked == true)
        {
            double Weight2 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
            double LowW = Weight2 * 24 * 1.4;
            String s = Convert.ToString(LowW);
           richTextBox1.Text = "The calories per day for low actaivity is : " + s;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you assign this function to all 3 radio buttons?

Comment: yes why not ....

Comment: Was checking because you didnt tell us you had...

Comment: btw cos its bugging me its spelt "activity" .. I see the same behavior if you go from 2-3 but this is only assigned to radiobutton 1.. which is logical, are you really sure you assigned this to all 3 radio buttons?

Answer (score 0):

I can only reproduce your behavior if your radiobutton1 is the only one with the code.  why would this be .. the code is run on changing of the checked value

- when you select radiobutton1 it would fire.
- when you then select either 2 or 3, it would fire because it now becomes unselected, lets pretend you selected 2.
- however, if you then select 3, the value of radiobutton1 hasnt changed, so the code doesnt fire.

as an example. I minimalized your code, assigned it to all 3 buttons and got this:

```
    if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "The calories per day for low activity is : x";
    }
    else if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "The calories per day for med activity is : x";
    }
    else if (radioButton3.Checked == true)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "The calories per day for hi activity is : x";
    }
    Text = "checked " + (sender as RadioButton).Name;
```

The last showing me which "sender" was the button that called the routine.  Just so I could check.  Now, in essence this code is inefficient because in theory once an item is selected, and you change it - the code is in effect called twice.

While it is a very low cost thing - it is something to be aware of.  you can mitigate that by checking the sender but if its a radiobutton using that to check that the value of checked is true and then proceeding to your code

Comment: thank you i manage to fix it by split them into 3 methods now its working perfectly

Comment: You didnt need 3 separate functions, but thats one way to do it